# Como buscar todos os registros no banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

> **Me ajudem ai pessoal!!!**

```
$BuscaProdutosAtivos = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_produtos p
                                      INNER JOIN tbl_categorias c ON c.cat_id = p.prod_categoria
                                      INNER JOIN tbl_variacoes v ON v.cod_prod = p.id
                                      WHERE p.prod_ativo = 1");

////////////////////////////////                                      
$BuscaProdutosAtivos->execute(); 
$BuscaProdutosAtivos->rowCount();
```

Estou buscando 3 tipos de informações dentro do banco de dados: primeiro eu busco um produto que esteja ativo para mostrar na loja, até ai tudo bem.

Depois eu busco a categoria a qual pertence este produto e também corre tudo bem.

O meu produto pode ser verde, amarelo ou azul e é isso que eu busco na tabela `tbl_variacoes` e tento colocar dentro de um dropdown e é ai que eu tenho problema porque ele retorna só a primeira variação, ou seja, só a primeira cor.

```
while($PA = $BuscaProdutosAtivos->fetch()){ ?>
    <select name="variacoes" class="form-control chosen-select" data-placeholder="Escolha a variação">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1"><?=$PA['cor']?></option>
    </select>
?>
```

> **Como retorno todas as variações dentro do dropdown?**

Este **[código](http://pastebin.com/WbUKQVdM)** me retorna todos os produtos da base que respondem aos requisitos. Se puder ajudar a compreender !!!!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Rodando a query diretamente no MySQL os registros esperados são retornados?

Comment: Não dá erro algum !!! Somente no list do dropdown ele pega só a primeira variação. Na verdade esse while é pra listar todos os produtos, então acho que precisa fazer mais alguma coisa para retornar as variações. Fiz um update da pergunta colocando link do código completo.

Comment: A query está retornando perfeitamente o que ela deve retornar que é todos os produtos ativos com pelo menos uma categoria e uma variação. Só falta retornar TODAS as variações.

Comment: Revisa esse `JOIN`, aparentemente ele está errado: `INNER JOIN tbl_variacoes v ON v.var_id = p.prod_categoria`, você está cruzando o `ID` da variação com o `ID` da categoria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com esta *query*, a consulta irá retornar todas as variações cadastradas em `tbl_variacoes`.

```
$BuscaProdutosAtivos = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_produtos p
                                      INNER JOIN tbl_categorias c ON c.cat_id = p.prod_categoria
                                      INNER JOIN tbl_variacoes v ON v.cod_prod = p.id
                                      WHERE p.prod_ativo = 1");
```

Vamos supor que você tenha 3 cores cadastradas como variações, na hora que fosse rodar o comando `while`, no resultado gerado, iria realizar 3 repetições. No seu atual código, irá lhe retornar 3 box do mesmo produto. Para evitar que isso aconteça, será necessário um pequeno ajuste na *query*:

```
$BuscaProdutosAtivos = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(v.cor) AS cores FROM tbl_produtos p
                                      INNER JOIN tbl_categorias c ON c.cat_id = p.prod_categoria
                                      INNER JOIN tbl_variacoes v ON v.cod_prod = p.id
                                      WHERE p.prod_ativo = 1 GROUP BY p.id");
```

Observe que no final da *query* incluí o `GROUP BY p.id`, que irá agrupar o resultado pelo id do produto em `tbl_produtos` e após o `SELECT *` incluí o `GROUP_CONCAT(v.cor) AS cores` que irá concatenar o resultado agrupado da coluna `v.cor`, separando por `,`, e defini o apelido como `cores`.

E no código que você compartilhou neste [link](http://pastebin.com/WbUKQVdM), será necessário realizar uma pequena alteração:

```
<select name="variacoes" class="form-control chosen-select" data-placeholder="Escolha a variação">
<option value=""></option>
<?php foreach(explode(',',$PA['cores']) as $cor) : ?>
    <option value="<?=$cor?>"><?=$cor?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Bom dia. Então a tabela variações está se relacionando com a tabela produtos, ou seja, tal produto tem tantas variações. No meu código deu-se a entender que variações se relacionava com a tabela categorias, o que não é verdade. Modifiquei a SQL para deixar isso claro. A resposta dessa forma continua valendo para está situação?

Comment: Sim. Porém, a tabela `tbl_variacoes` precisará ter a coluna `cod_prod`.